# Why should computer and TV be turned off before plugging in an HDMI cable?

Tags: hdmi, hotplug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is HDMI hot pluggable?](https://superuser.com/questions/440959/is-hdmi-hot-pluggable)

I just bought [an Amazon HDMI+Ethernet cable](http://www.amazon.de/AmazonBasics-Hochgeschwindigkeits-HDMI-Kabel-mit-Ethernet-Meter/dp/B003L1ZYYM). Enclosed was the following friendly node on yellow paper in various languages:

[image: Warning label]

So far, I assumed that HDMI is designed to be "hot-pluggable". Is this just a "better safe than sorry, we don't want to get sued if anything breaks" kind of warning or is there a real, technical reason for powering down your computer and TV before connecting them?

Comment: The danger is that there is some voltage potential between the devices, which could lead to a shock hazard.  This possible with any two plugged-in devices, if the ground wires are not connected and there is leakage in the devices, but not a problem 99.99% of the time.  And simply turning off the devices does not remove this hazard, so the warning is kind useless.

Comment: Not an "exact duplicate", BTW.

Comment: Better safe than sorry?